# Stacked and grouped chart ggplot2 combined for all entries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a similar problem to this one: [Combine Stacked and Grouped chart ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750222/combine-stacked-and-grouped-chart-ggplot2)

I have data that looks like this:

[image]

What I want to create is `genom_bar` chart in `ggplot` that look like this:

[image]

Where the blue area represents the `gender` part of the `age_group`. My code looks like this:

```
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=`Green cars are nice`, y=round(percentage, digits = 2), fill = Age_group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge()) +
    facet_grid(.~residence) +
    xlab(filename) +
    ylab(NULL) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1)) +
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14)) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))
    
  
  p
```

What do I need to add in order to make the bar look like in my paint made picture? I had troubles understanding the code shown in the example from SO that I posted.

Edit:

```
Berlin  18-39   Woman   Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
Berlin  18-39   Woman   Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
Berlin  18-39   Woman   Don't know  0.563183402 0.003094414
Berlin  40-70   Woman   Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
Berlin  40-70   Woman   Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
Berlin  40-70   Woman   Don't know  0.563183402 0.003094414
London  18-39   Woman   Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
London  18-39   Woman   Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
London  18-39   Woman   Don't know  0.563183402 0.003094414
London  40-70   Woman   Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
London  40-70   Woman   Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
London  40-70   Woman   Don't know  0.563183402 0.003094414
Berlin  18-39   Man Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
Berlin  18-39   Man Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
Berlin  18-39   Man Don't know  0.563183402 0.003094414
Berlin  40-70   Man Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
Berlin  40-70   Man Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
Berlin  40-70   Man Don't know  0.563183402 0.003094414
London  18-39   Man Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
London  18-39   Man Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
London  18-39   Man Don't know  0.563183402 0.003094414
London  40-70   Man Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
London  40-70   Man Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
London  40-70   Man Don't know  0.563183402 0.003094414
```

Comment: Can you post your table as code instead of image? It would be easier to help you.

Comment: Done. The values differ - but that does not matter.

Comment: You've run out of dimensions here. You can have any 2 of stacked, dodged and faceted, but not all 3. Your options are to have interactions on the x axis, so the plot would be as you want except you would need to do it all in a single panel with a line separating the plots, or (more easily) create the two facets as separate plots and stitch them together using `cowplot` or `patchwork`

Comment: @KGB91 actually, the proper way to show your data is with `dput(YOUR_DF)` so that we can copy/paste seamlessly :)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `dput` - I always wondered how you did those nice data outputs here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of `ggplot` is quite opinionated about the number of variables you should try to embed on a plot. Thus, this is not doable the way you asked.

A few things to consider, none of them exactly what you asked for, none of them are necessarily good visualizations.

Here's your data (I changed the names so you'll need to adjust them to those on your local setup). Also, "Don't know" was codified as "Don't".

```
df <- read.delim(text=
                   "residence   age sex agree   persons percent
Berlin  18-39   Woman   Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
Berlin  18-39   Woman   Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
Berlin  18-39   Woman   Don't   0.563183402 0.003094414
Berlin  40-70   Woman   Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
Berlin  40-70   Woman   Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
Berlin  40-70   Woman   Don't   0.563183402 0.003094414
London  18-39   Woman   Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
London  18-39   Woman   Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
London  18-39   Woman   Don't   0.563183402 0.003094414
London  40-70   Woman   Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
London  40-70   Woman   Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
London  40-70   Woman   Don't   0.563183402 0.003094414
Berlin  18-39   Man Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
Berlin  18-39   Man Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
Berlin  18-39   Man Don't   0.563183402 0.003094414
Berlin  40-70   Man Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
Berlin  40-70   Man Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
Berlin  40-70   Man Don't   0.563183402 0.003094414
London  18-39   Man Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
London  18-39   Man Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
London  18-39   Man Don't   0.563183402 0.003094414
London  40-70   Man Agree   1.689550205 0.009283243
London  40-70   Man Disagree    3.942283812 0.0216609
London  40-70   Man Don't   0.563183402 0.003094414
")
```

You *could* try to use color to codify this. The plot is quite bad and I bet you could potentially find a combination of `colors` and `fills` that is less disgusting. I wouldn't recommend this to my worst enemy but be my guest.

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x=agree,
           y=round(percent, digits = 2),
           fill = age,
           color=sex)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray50", "white"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "black"))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position=position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  facet_grid(.~residence)
```

[image]

Another option is creating an interaction variable. But you don't get to dodge and stack.

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x=agree,
           y=round(percent, digits = 2),
           fill = interaction(sex, age))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray50", "lightblue", "black", "blue"))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color="white") +
  facet_grid(.~residence)
```

[image]

Finally, consider using `facet_wrap()`. This can allow you to stack as you wanted, but you will not have the age comparison side by side

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x=agree,
           y=round(percent, digits = 2),
           fill = interaction(sex, age))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray50", "lightblue", "black", "blue"))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color="white") +
  facet_grid(age~residence)
```

[image]

Of note, rounding percent to 2 digits produces it to disappear (the value gets rounded to 0.0). Not sure if the images you uploaded were actually rounded or the data has an extra zero. Here's the last plot with no `round(...)`

[image]